# Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error, and I don't know why it keeps to assign `undefined` to those elements.

```
function filterToDo(e) {
    const todos = toDoList.childNodes;
    
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = 'flex';
                break;
            case "completed":
                if(todo.classList.contains("completed")){
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = 'none';
                } 
            case "uncompleted":
                if(!todo.classList.contains("completed")){
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = 'none';
                } 

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `todo.classList` is `undefined`, so you can't call `contains()` on it. If you do `console.log(todo)`, what does it return?

Comment: `todo.classList` -> This is undefined. Calling `contains()` on it is failing.

Comment: I would assume there are textNodes inside your `childNodes` which do not have a class hence the script is failing.Check for the existence of the `classList` before calling `contains()` on it

Comment: you right , it returns undefined. But how do i solve this?

Comment: `childNodes` returns all nodes, including text nodes (not elements). Text nodes don't have `classList` property. Try to filter `childNodes` to iterate only on html elements.

Comment: Try to use `toDoList.children` instead of `toDoList.childNodes`

Answer (score 1):

Try to filter out text nodes, which are not html elements, hence they don't have classList property:

```js
function filterToDo(e) {
    const todos = [...toDoList.childNodes].filter(node => node instanceof HTMLElement);
    
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    //…
    });
}
```

Or

```js
function filterToDo(e) {
    const todos = Array.from(toDoList.childNodes).filter(node => node instanceof HTMLElement);
    
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    //…
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, you can't call something that isnt defined, the solution would be to check to see if classList exists at all before calling contains on it.

here is a solution with optional changing
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
function filterToDo(e) {
    const todos = toDoList.childNodes;
    
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = 'flex';
                break;
            case "completed":
                if(todo.classList?.contains("completed")){
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = 'none';
                } 
            case "uncompleted":
                if(!todo.classList?.contains("completed")){
                    todo.style.display = 'flex';
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = 'none';
                } 
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to get todos using document.querySelector, I came across all the elements that have the todo class.
Then, for completed and uncompleted, I came to className and checked the completed class to see if it existed.

```
function filterTodo(event) {
  const type = event.target.value
  const todos = document.querySelectorAll(".todo")

  for (const todo of todos) {
    switch (type) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex"
        break
      case "completed":
        todo.className.includes("completed")
          ? (todo.style.display = "flex")
          : (todo.style.display = "none")
        break
      case "uncompleted":
        !todo.className.includes("completed")
          ? (todo.style.display = "flex")
          : (todo.style.display = "none")
        break
    }
  }
}
```